# how to load other html page in java script

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onload

i have a task to navigate multiple html files from local drive when action is triggered but i cant navigate to other html file its keep on loading the sample first html file

**here my sample code :**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {


document.getElementById('continue').onclick = function(){

var name = document.getElementById('Name').value;
var company = document.getElementById('company').value;
console.log(company)

if (name.length >0 && company.length>0){

window.location = 'reg2.html'
}

}

});
```

Comment: try adding absolute path or path relative to host.

Comment: Maybe you don’t want to do the same thing twice here …? You are setting the new location once, without any conditions - and then inside the if block you are doing it again. Supposed sense behind that is what?

Comment: check update code

Comment: I just created html file, added a button and two inputs, your code works fine. Maybe you're not showing us everything?

Comment: im using this line on my js file document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var reg2 = window.location.href + '/reg2.html';
window.location = reg2;
```

Comment: is your HTML file in the root directory?

Comment: its in same directory